# Can I have a switch statement inside kinetic drawFunc? I tried that but failed... I guess NO?

Tags: kineticjs

var s= new Kinetic.Shape({ drawFunc: function (c) {
    c.beginPath();

```
c.fillStrokeShape(this); c.stroke()
}, stroke: 'black', fill: 'none', strokeWidth: 1, /*id: tid + '_'+which,*/ visible: show
```

});

Comment: Sure you can.  Your code shows no switch statement(?), but remember that `this` inside drawFunc is the node itself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yFQ9F/3/   I cann't move the switch statement to the outside, the example is just a simple switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code has numerous typos:**

You define `loc` as a number

```
var loc=10;
```

But read it as a string

```
case "left":
case "right":
```

Also you have un-terminated quotes on both your case statements.

It should look more like this:

```
var xaxis = 50;
var loc="left";
var middle = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function (context) {
        context.beginPath();
        switch(loc){
            case "left":
                xaxis=10;
                break;
            case "right":
                xaxis=20;
                break;
        }
        context.moveTo(25 + xaxis, 125);
        context.arc(25+xaxis, 135, 10, 1.50*Math.PI, 3.50*Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStrokeShape(this);
        context.stroke()
    },
    stroke: 'black',
    fill: '',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    id: '_middle'
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. because of this, I know it is possible.